# issue with elastic edior plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with the plugin elastic editor for wordpress themes.
The problem is when I try to save the theme, the plugin not save it,
and I cant't see it in themes folder.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow these steps to install the plugin and does number 4 happen?

1. Unzip the elastic.zip file
2. Upload the folder to your /wp-content/plugins/ directory
3. Activate the Elastic Theme Editor on the 'Plugins' page.
4. A subpage for Elastic will appear in the Themes menu.